# PyInstaller: ImportError: cannot import name 'ccompiler' from partially initialized module 'numpy.distutils'

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

After freezing my program with PyInstaller, I encountered following error while trying to run the executable:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'

After adding `numpy.distutils` to hidden imports, I am getting a new error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ccompiler' from partially initialized module 'numpy.distutils' (most likely due to a circular import)

with which I don't know what to do.
Those are imports from my code :

```
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
import fiona
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterio import features
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
import PySimpleGUI as sg
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to collect all submodules of `Numpy`

```sh
--collect-submodules numpy
```

then, you may get a new error or others

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.unixccompiler'

Adding them to hidden imports

```sh
--hidden-import distutils.unixccompiler
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update to Pyinstaller 4.8. They fix this error in this release.